# SQL - How to join top ordered results from pictures table with product table?

Tags: sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I have a products table, and a pictures table as such:

### Products

- id
- name
- model

### Pictures

- id
- pid
- url
- order

The picture for each pid with the highest order is the cover picture. There can be more than 1 picture per product.

I want to join this result when I query the products, so it would show these result

```
id, name, model, url (cover picture/highest order for this pid)
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I'm going nuts trying to get it to work. So far I've manage to get it to work by joining the picture as below, but I can't get it to join only the picture with the top order...

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       p.model,
       x.url 
  FROM products p 
  JOIN pictures x ON (p.id = x.pid)
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: I'm on PHP/MySQL using MYISAM..

Comment: The other way I was tried to do this successfully was calling another function to fetch the picture while looping through the product results on the view page itself. Thought that was a not very optimized way of doing it. Would you guys think that would be a simplier way of doing it ? Looking at the current solution now, we seem to be running a query for every result anyways, so thats about the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       p.model,
       x.url 
  FROM PRODUCTS p 
  JOIN PICTURES x ON x.pid = p.id
  JOIN (SELECT t.pid,
               MAX(t.order) AS max_order
          FROM PICTURES t
      GROUP BY t.pid) y ON y.pid = x.pid
                       AND y.max_order = x.order
```

Comment: wow thanks for the quick response! That worked like a charm, though I don't fully understand the 2nd join/subquery yet, I will study it. Thanks a bunch man!

Comment: If 2 records have the same maximum order then there will be duplicates.

Comment: adding GROUP BY p.id at the end seems to fix the duplicates.